# Python Regex - Find up to space but not including

Tags: python, regex

I've got a string like so

```
 AT 4:30am some other words maybe another time 3:20pm
```

Which will be a little different each time but the time I want is always the first and will always contain the first digit in the string. The time format varies with am,pm, with colon, without colon and with no suffix.

The following almost gets me there but in the case of 4:15 it'll also include the space after. I could strip it after but would rather get rid of it in The first place. I think I need to use a + symbol but I'm not getting the right results.

```
\d.+?(am|pm|\s)
```

Comment: Maybe `\d.+?(am|pm|(?!\S))` or `\d[\d:]*(?:\s*(?:am|pm))?` will work for you. Could you please provide a comprehensive set of test cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `re.search()` function and specific regex pattern:

```
import re

s = 'AT 4:30am some other words maybe another time 3:20pm'
result = re.search(r'\b\d+(:\d+)?(am|pm)?\b', s).group()
print(result)
```

The output:

```
4:30am
```

Comment: I didn't think about using word boundaries and it appears to catch all the cases I mentioned. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not sure whether the `\b`s are mandatory: the inside of those is quite strict anyway, and will not match any space.

Answer (score 1):

Current One that is working for me:

```
import re

regex = '4:30am some other words maybe another time 3:20pm'

string = = re.findall('\d*:\d*[p][m]|\d*:\d*[a][m]', regex)
```

Expression itself is:

```
\d*:\d*[p][m]|\d*:\d*[a][m]
```